# R: How To: ggbarplot to actual values

Tags: r

In R studtio, using ggbarplot we can get the avergae and the standard error of groups based on a column. For example, grouping of data based on "dose" as shown [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggpubr/versions/0.2.3/topics/ggbarplot) (copy of the code is given below)

```
df3 <- ToothGrowth
ggbarplot(df3, x = "dose", y = "len", add = "mean_se")
```

[image]

The figure generated is good. However, in addition to the figure, i would also like to obtain the calculated data in a dataframe like..

[image]

Could someone kildly help me to obtain such dataframe from ggbarplot?

Comment: Where does `ggbarplot` come from? And what are the numbers you want in the data frame—you say "average" which is ambiguous. Mean? I'm also unsure why you would expect to get a data frame from a plotting function. Why not just calculate those summary stats yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task can be beautifully fulfilled using the dplyr package which is part of the tidyverse.

```
# Group the dataframe by dose
df3 %>% group_by(dose) %>%
# Calculate group means and group standard deviation
  summarise(mean_length = mean(len), sd = sd(len))
```

```
   dose mean_length    sd
  <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
1   0.5        10.6  4.50
2   1          19.7  4.42
3   2          26.1  3.77
```

You may notice that I've used the "pipe operator" %>% it "pipes" the output of the statement to the left, as the first argument into the function to the right.

I hope this solves your question. :)